# Terraform - Multiple subnets with same aws_instance resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm attempting to deploy multiple EC2 instances, each in different subnets using  the same `aws_instance` resource block.

When I set the count parameter to more than one server it establishes them all in the same subnet.

Is there a way to accomplish this via Terraform?

Below you'll find my Terraform block:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
  ami                    = "${var.ec2_ami}"
  instance_type          = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group}"]

  subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
  count     = "${var.count}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "${var.root_volume_size}"
    volume_type = "${var.root_volume_type}"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "${var.app_name}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your terraform sample you are using `count` to create multiple instances of the resource, but are specifying the same subnet for each instance (`var.subnet_id`).

You can use the count index to set resource properties to different values for each instance. For example, you can define your list of subnets as a variable and then use [element()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-) to pick one based on the count index.

```
variable "subnet_ids" {
  default =  [ "s1", "s2", "s3" ]
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance"
{
  count = "${var.count}"
  subnet_id = "${element(var.subnet_ids, count.index)}"

 # rest of config as before...
}
```

Comment: I'd probably recommend the `list[index]` syntax over `element(list, index)` nowadays but this is definitely the right way to do this. Even better when you combine this with the `aws_subnet_ids` data source!

Comment: The `list[index]` syntax doesn't seem to handle the case that index is greater than the length of the list, whereas `element()` does, so I'd think that that might still be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define another aws_instance block to achieve that. AWS API also does not support this. When you create an EC2 instance using the RunInstances API, it will launch all instances (as part of the single request) in the same subnet.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!
Is there no way to make a loop or something like that with Terraform that runs the same aws_instance's block but with only different subnetIDs?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to deploy multiple EC2 instances, each in different subnets using the same aws_instance resource block.

You can use the following workaround

```
data aws_subnet_ids current {
   vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
   count     = "${var.count}"
   subnet_id = tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.current.ids)[count.index % length(data.aws_subnet_ids.current.ids)]

   # rest of config as before...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can use for_each today as well:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance"
{
  for_each = var.subnet_ids
  subnet_id = each.value

  #....
}
```